# Self-contained toolchain for Qt for x86 Linux/Windows

Tags: qt, cross-platform, toolchain

I am setting up a Qt project which will be cross-copiled for a given display (running on ARM/Linux). The display will come with a self-contained cross-build toolchain which comprises Qt libraries with a specific Qt version (probably 5.15).

Now I would like to use a specific "static" toolchain incl. Qt libraries to also generate x86-builds of this Qt project (for testing, simulation; building/running on Linux and maybe also on Windows).

I'd avoid using the GCC and Qt development files introduced by the Linux package manager (e.g. `apt`), because the are not tied to a specific Qt version, i.e. upgrading the OS would always come with the risk to introduce build problems or break compatibility completely.

**Are there good-practice approaches to achieve this?**

So far I see three options:

**Use a docker image**

Possible problems:

- Finding a image with the correct Qt version
- building the Qt application would then work, but to execute it, the compatible Qt LGPL shared libs need to be available to the Qt application binary

**Use a x86 -> x86 "standalone" toolchain**

Find some standalone x86-toolchain analog to [those](https://toolchains.bootlin.com/) (x86 -> x86), but additionaly...

- it would either have to come with the Qt development files in the correct version
- or we would have to [build](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/build-sources.html) the [Qt sources](https://wiki.qt.io/Building_Qt_5_from_Git#Getting_the_source_code) with this toolchain, and then extend the toolchain with the Qt built artifacts

Would be the preferred solution (and currently seems to be the most feasible of the approaches I can think of).

**Virtual machine**

Possible problems:

- Finding a OS version with the correct Qt version
- Select a OS version that contains the correct Qt version via package manager.

Not very elegant.

**Qt online installer**

- only provides a limited choice of Qt versions (as of today: 5.15.2, 6.2.4, 6.3.2, 6.4.0) which is probably subject to change in the future

Comment: Why not the Qt Online installer ? You can choose the version you want. Another approach is to recompile Qt from source on your x86 platform.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of the online installer and will have a look at that.

Comment: The online installer is probably not what I'm looking for, see description in the updated question. I'll look at compiling from sources, the Qt homepage provides a description.